# Why does kerberos suddenly stop working with VSCODE and I lose permissions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, kerberos, vscode-remote

I get the error:

```
Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+ampere1.stanford.edu/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/evaporate/evaporate/run_profiler.py' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/evaporate/evaporate/run_profiler.py')
```

which is weird because see that I have the kerberos token just fine:

```
(data_quality) brandomiranda~/.ssh ❯ klist -l
    Name                      Cache name                                 Expires
* brando9@CS.STANFORD.EDU   API:99A7672E-C880-45C8-A5CE-8B95DA0C9DF2   Jul 26 01:12:13 202
```

I can ssh into the server from the terminal fine too without password:

```
(data_quality) brandomiranda~ ❯ ssh brando9@ampere1.stanford.edu
Last login: Tue Jul 25 15:05:38 2023 from 172.24.69.154
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 ampere1.stanford.edu
 Ubuntu 20.04 (5.4.0-122-generic)
 128 x AMD EPYC 7543 32-Core Processor, 1.96 TiB RAM, 8.00 GiB swap

 enp139s0f1: 172.24.75.12
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
   -> For help or to report problems, go to http://support.cs.stanford.edu

(maf) brando9@ampere1~ $
```

btw this is the config file

```
(data_quality) brandomiranda~/.ssh ❯ cat config
Host *.stanford.edu
   # HostName *.stanford.edu
   User brando9
   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
   GSSAPIAuthentication yes%
```

so what is the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have tickets after connecting to the server? Are they being correctly delegated? Can you access `/lfs/ampere1` from the remote shell?